# Is this incremental Saving Formula Correct?

Tags: savings, calculation

I'm planning to save some money.
I earn in Pakistani Rupees. At the time of posting `1Usd` = `Rs 123.12`.

I came up with an idea to save a certain amount each month and add additional 10% of the saved amount.

So the formula become `(total savings * 0.1) + total savings + this month contribution`

[image]

Comment: The math seems correct. What exactly are you confused about?

Comment: Would the 10% come from you or the bank?

Comment: At 10%, the interest on the first 10,000 _alone_ after 10 years is 24,553.  Compound interest results can be astonishing at higher interest rates for longer periods.

Comment: @DStanley I'm panning to add 10% myself

Comment: @Nosjack because the growth is insanely exponential.

Comment: @JunaidQadirShekhanzai Exactly. Since the growth compounds, the formula for the amount in a given period is `P * e^(rt)` where t is the number of periods and r is the interest rate per period. So it is _literally_ exponential growth.

Answer (score 1):

If you could earn 10% monthly interest on your savings, then this calculation might make sense. Assuming you almost certainly can't, you are proposing a plan in which the amount you save each month increases very rapidly. Why do you think you will be able to afford to contribute more than Rs 28,000 per month by a year from now, if you can't currently? That money has to come from somewhere.

Comment: I'm not earning the 10% as such, just want to add it on my own on the saved amount the previous month.

Comment: @JunaidQadirShekhanzai How? Where will you be getting ever increasing amounts of money from?

Comment: RS.10,000 in today's USD is only 81.18. i'm earning enough to save $200+ each month.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your math is correct. These two options basically show exponential and linear growth respectively. A 10% increase in deposits each month is very, very large.

If you expand your math out to 24 months and make a graph, the difference is very noticeable:

[image]

On month 24 you add nearly $80,000 *on top of* your base $10,000. And that additional amount keeps growing.